# Python code to check repetition in a string

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to build logic in programming. I need to write a python function that takes string as input and checks whether any character appears more than once. The function should return True if there are no repetitions and False otherwise. I have searched online and found several examples related to it. I wrote the code and it seemed fine initially but then I realized my mistake and now I'm not getting how should I go about it. Please guide

```
def repfree(S):   
    for char in S:
        if S.count(char) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Wouldn’t swapping the True and False solve the issue?

Comment: Right now you check if there are repetitions, but you want to di the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here, you can create a character list to keep track of the characters that have already occurred in `S`.

**Have a look at the code below, hope it helps:>**

```
def repfree(S):   
    freq = []
    for char in S:
        # if the character is already in list that means S contains repeated char
        if char in freq:
            return False
        else:
            freq.append(char)

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a `set`

```py
def repfree(s):
    char_set = set()
    for c in s:
         char_set.append(c)
     return len(char_set) == len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try on the following code.

```
def rep_free(text):   
    return len(text) != len(set(text))
```

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections module.)

From [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using set data structure of python, set is having a property where it will always have unique characters only.

```
string="country"
def repetion(string):
    if len(set(string)) == len(string):
       print("string is having unique chars")
    else:
       print("chars are different")
```